# How can I run my pipenv flask server with PM2 or similar service?

Tags: python, flask, pm2, pipenv

I have a flask server that I run within a pipenv environment. My folder structure looks like this

- app

  - backend

    - app.py
  - frontend

My app.py file looks like this:

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect, generate_csrf
from flask_login import LoginManager

from .models import db, User
from .api.user_routes import user_routes
from .api.auth_routes import auth_routes
from .api.s3_upload import s3_routes
from .api.images_routes import images_routes
from .api.comments_routes import comments_routes
from .api.tags_routes import tags_routes

from .seeds import seed_commands

from .config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)

# Setup login manager
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'auth.unauthorized'


@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


# Tell flask about our seed commands
app.cli.add_command(seed_commands)

app.config.from_object(Config)
app.register_blueprint(user_routes, url_prefix='/api/users')
app.register_blueprint(auth_routes, url_prefix='/api/auth')
app.register_blueprint(s3_routes, url_prefix='/api/s3')
app.register_blueprint(images_routes, url_prefix='/api/images')
app.register_blueprint(comments_routes, url_prefix='/api/comments')
app.register_blueprint(tags_routes, url_prefix='/api/tags')

db.init_app(app)
Migrate(app, db)

# Application Security
CORS(app)


# Since we are deploying with Docker and Flask,
# we won't be using a buildpack when we deploy to Heroku.
# Therefore, we need to make sure that in production any
# request made over http is redirected to https.
# Well.........
@app.before_request
def https_redirect():
    if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'production':
        if request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') == 'http':
            url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
            code = 301
            return redirect(url, code=code)


@app.after_request
def inject_csrf_token(response):
    response.set_cookie(
        'csrf_token',
        generate_csrf(),
        secure=True if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'production' else False,
        samesite='Strict' if os.environ.get(
            'FLASK_ENV') == 'production' else None,
        httponly=True)
    return response


@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def react_root(path):
    if path == 'favicon.ico':
        return app.send_static_file('favicon.ico')
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

I was able to start my frontend with PM2 just fine, but I can't seem to find a way to run my flask server within pipenv.

In development normally do

pipenv shell
flask run

But as soon as I close my production server, this stops. I tried

pipenv shell
pm2 start app.py --name backend --interpreter python3

but this errors out

Comment: you must run pm2 as external process, like this `pm2 start "gunicorn main:app ......." -name <service_name>`